# How to fix a program that incorrectly calculates the percentages of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, percentage

I am trying to find the frequency of each letter in a document, so this program counts up the number of occurrences of each letter, and then finds the total number of letters. Then it's supposed to find the frequency, the problem is it counts the letters correctly and the total, but the percentages incorrectly. How do I calculate the percentage?

```
  //find number of occurrences for each letter
    String[] letter = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};      
    int[] count = new int[26];
    int totalCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < subset.length(); i++)
    {
        char letters = subset.charAt(i);
        if(letters == 'a')
            count[0]++;
        else if(letters == 'b')
            count[1]++;
        else if(letters == 'c')
            count[2]++;
        else if(letters == 'd')
            count[3]++;
        else if(letters == 'e')
            count[4]++;
        else if(letters == 'f')
            count[5]++;
        else if(letters == 'g')
            count[6]++;
        else if(letters == 'h')
            count[7]++;
        else if(letters == 'i')
            count[8]++;
        else if(letters == 'j')
            count[9]++;
        else if(letters == 'k')
            count[10]++;
        else if(letters == 'l')
            count[11]++;
        else if(letters == 'm')
            count[12]++;
        else if(letters == 'n')
            count[13]++;
        else if(letters == 'o')
            count[14]++;
        else if(letters == 'p')
            count[15]++;
        else if(letters == 'q')
            count[16]++;
        else if(letters == 'r')
            count[17]++;
        else if(letters == 's')
            count[18]++;
        else if(letters == 't')
            count[19]++;
        else if(letters == 'u')
            count[20]++;
        else if(letters == 'v')
            count[21]++;
        else if(letters == 'w')
            count[22]++;
        else if(letters == 'x')
            count[23]++;
        else if(letters == 'y')
            count[24]++;
        else if(letters == 'z')
            count[25]++;
    }

    //find total characters in document                
    double[] frequency = new double[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        totalCount += count[i];
        frequency[i] = ((double)count[i] / (totalCount + 1)) * 100;        //the problem
    }
    System.out.println(totalCount); 


    //for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        //{
        //    frequency[i] = (double)(count[i] / totalCount * 100);
        //}


    //print 
    System.out.println(" Letter  Occurrences  Frequency");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("  " + letter[i] + "\t  " + count[i] + "\t       " + df.format(frequency[i]));
    }
```

Comment: *"the problem is it counts the letters correctly and the total, but the percentages incorrectly. "* could you please be more specific about that?

Comment: You should also consider to change your huge ifelse block.
every char is an integer.

Consider this:

'b'='a'+1
so why not:
char char=c;
int id=c-'a'
count[id]++;

Comment: And hint: you want to read about Java Maps for example. Your code is overly complex; and could be reduced significantly.

Comment: Agreeing with @GhostCat, code that uses arrays directly is generally more complex and to little advantage. You'll soon see how to keep code closer to the concepts and less cluttered with implementation details. "counts up the number of occurrences of each letter": suggests `Map<Character, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();`….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency needs to be calculated after you have the totalCount:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
    totalCount += count[i]; 
} 
System.out.println(totalCount);  

System.out.println(" Letter Occurrences Frequency"); 

System.out.println("--------------------------------");     
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
    frequency[i] = ((double)count[i] / (totalCount + 1)) * 100;
    System.out.println(" " + letter[i] + "\t " + count[i] + "\t " + df.format(frequency[i])); 
}
```

**Side note**

- You don't need a for loop for totalCount since it's just the length of the string (i.e. `totalCount = subset.length()`)
- you wouldn't need 25 if else statements to find letter counts... Just do: 
  `count[subset.charAt(i) - 61]++;`
  *61 is the ASCII value for letter 'a'*

Comment: More directly, 61 is the single UTF-16 code unit (`char`) value of 'a'. Further, `subset.charAt(i) - 'a'` is  much easier to read.